# Selecting a character that's in a line twice with regex

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

I have a code setup like this:

```
'olderVehicleHdr' : '#cft("We can still find you the right tires. Tell us what you drive.")#'
    ,'weCanStillHelpYou' : '#cft("We can still help.")#'
    ,'name' : '#cft("Name")#'
```

I need to switch the `' '` over to `" "` but there is A LOT of these in this file. and I'd rather not do each one individually so I thought I would try a regex setup. However I don't want the single quotes around the `cft` and ending `#` sign to be selected, since they need to be single quotes in order for the double quotes to work.

For example: I want to take `'name' : '#cft("Name")#'` and turn the single quotes around `name` and make them double quotes like so: `"name" : '#cft("Name")#'`

This regex will be used on sublime to search for the appropriate characters and replace them. So my question is, can you make a regex that only selects the single quotes at the begining of the line and replace them? Without disturbing the second set of single quotes?

I've tried some of the `lookbehind` methods but they don't seem to work either. Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, I have actually found a regex combo which seems to do the trick:

`(?<![a-z]|\(|\\)'(?=[a-z]|[A-Z]|[0-1])|(?<=[a-z]|[0-9])'(?!\))` It's a tad bit sloppy but I only need it very rarely, and it works to me needs for right now. Thank you for your time to try and help me solve this!

Answer (score 0):

if sublimetext3 regex engine is based on PCRE use this pattern

```
'#cft[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|'
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/155)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it is, as this does not work through sublime text.